# Attempting to enter recovery mode and go to root

Tags: 12.04, recovery-mode

I have attempted to follow directions as listed in the "[How do I reset a lost administrative password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)" question. The procedure is also listed in "how do I boot into recovery mode".

I get through the initial steps but the arrow keys stop working when I get to the Recovery Menu. They work fine selecting the boot option.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin) as a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing 'r' for root - this should highlight the root entry of the menu, and then you can press 'enter' to get the root terminal open

Comment: I had attempted to hit Enter on the 1st item where it was, with no result. I don't think it's accepting any keyboard input.

Comment: Thanks gonna make it tough.  Are you using a wireless keyboard?